# File System Monitor for multiple files at once in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script which sits there and waits for files to be added to a folder. If it detects any, I want it to then move them to another folder.

There are quite a few articles online with code similar to that shown below, but none of these seem to work if you put more than one file into the folder at once.

```
$folder = "d:\Logs\temp"
$filter = "*.xml"                           # <-- set this according to your requirements
$destination = "d:\Logs\XML\"
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
 IncludeSubdirectories = $false       # <-- set this according to your requirements
 NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
 $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
 $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
 $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
 $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
 Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
 Move-Item $path -Destination $destination -Force -Verbose # Force will overwrite files with same name
}
```

Not only do they not work, they seem to get stuck completely. Does anyone have any ideas how this could be done? In my case, a whole batch of XML files will be deposited into the folder at once and need to be processed in turn.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running this under? It works for me with v3 but not v2.

Comment: Hmm, something odd going on here - I have previously been running v3 but I've done a $psversiontable.psversion and I'm now seeing v2... thanks for the nod in the right direction, I'll look into this!

Comment: Take a look at the answer provided; Accept or vote-up any that have helped.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option for doing something like this would be setting up a scheduled task that runs a PowerShell script every 3-5mins. The script you could call would be something simple like this:

```
$folder = "d:\Logs\temp"
$destination = "d:\Logs\XML\"
$filter = "*.xml"
Move-Item  ($folder+"\"+$filter) $destination -force
```

This will move only file that match the `$filter` out of the start `$folder` and put them all in the `$desination` folder.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/schedule-a-task

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, besides the last line, which seems to be the only one you wrote so lets start there.
`Move-Item $path -Destination $destination -Force -Verbose # Force will overwrite files with same name`
and destination being `$destination = "d:\Logs\XML\"`

Literally, copy/move item takes in the fullpath of source and fullpath of destination. Although your trying to copy into the folder logs/xml, literally you are copying the src to a file "xml" in the folder "logs"

Hope you understand the concept, if you dont oh well, just use this...
`join-path $destination $name` before you move item

PS.. this completely stuck thing your referring to. As you may know, normally in powershell scripts they can error and completely move on, because scripts are compiled at run time by line, unlike many programming languages. Using powershell as events running as background processes does not maintain this behavior, in my experience.

The only fix to that problem I have found is error checking. Make sure a file is there before you try to copy it. Make sure your folder is there before you try to copy to it... Worse comes to worse just take the code out of the register event, test it to make sure it never generates red text, and then you should be good.

Comment: Don't build paths via string concatenation. Use `Join-Path` instead.

Comment: Yeah just looked at my answer and it was a little over engineered; I have made it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This is now working, I think the problem was that I had replaced some of the variables with references to an array object which was an imported config file and that was causing issues.